# open a folder with several files in python

Tags: python, files, directory

How can I open a folder with several files in it? 
I tested this codes but it returns an strange answer.

```
import os
for ZebRa in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    num_words = 0
    for line in ZebRa:
        words = line.split ()
        num_words += len (words)
print ("The number of words:", num_words)
```

Just returns 9. But it should count the number of words in 7 files, 70 text files.

Comment: Im sorry, but this question is not Ubuntu specific, and is therefore off topic

Comment: It must be me, but what should it do exactly? Count the words in the files?

Comment: I have a folder named ZebRa. In this folder I have 7 files. In each file I have about 7-9 text files. I want to count all of the words in these files. But I don't know how?!

Comment: Still not sure: in each *file* there are 7-9 *files*?

Comment: But then the answer is simple aint it: you are counting files inside Zebra  . and .. too ;)

Comment: 1 folder named ZebRa. 7 file folders, in each one there are 7-9 text files.

Comment: Put a print after "words=..." ;)

Comment: Your code does not make sense. `ZebRa` will be a string, not a file. Maybe you want to use `line in open(ZebRa, 'r')`? I suppose `num_words = 0` should be initialized in second line.

Comment: Generic programming questions should be asked on [so].

Answer (score 2):

Do you need Python? You can count words using the command line tool [`wc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wc.1):

```
wc -w *
```

`wc` (short for word count) is a handy tool to count words, characters or lines in text files. Open a terminal, navigate to the folder containing the files you want to count words and run the command above. The first parameter `-w` means to count words (as opposed to lines or characters). You can pass file names to count in specific files or use wild cards, such as `*` to count words in all files in the current folder.

In case your files are located in sub folders the easiest would be to use `find` to get a list of the files:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -w {} +
```

Comment: Hi. Could you pls explain more?

Comment: @LJS could you be a bit more precise with questions? :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, your code is not really clear to me. One of the mistakes you make is that you put the line`num_words = 0` inside the loop, which means that on every subfolder, you would start counting from 0.

*If* you want to use python, what would work anyway is to use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.walk), which would count the words in all files in a directory and its subdirectories, no matter how they are arranged:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
dr = "/path/to/ZebRa"; n_words = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for file in files:
        with open(root+"/"+file) as r:
            n_words += len(r.read().split())
print(n_words)
```

*Note(s)*

1. Keep in mind that if you (ever) edited the text files with e.g. `gedit`, `gedit` probably made (hidden) backup files, named `filename~`. These files will also be read, unless you tell the script not to, which pollutes the word count.
2. Also keep in mind that the script will break if it runs into unreadable files, again, unless you tell it to pass if it can't read a file.

Editing both issues into the script, would make:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
dr = "/path/to/ZebRa"; n_words = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for f in [f for f in files if not f.startswith(".") and not f.endswith("~")]:
        try: 
            with open(root+"/"+f) as r:
                n_words += len(r.read().split())
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
print(n_words)
```